# Image slider with json data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I want to build an image slider that shows images with related heading and detail for each item. The data needs to be pulled from JSON. For example I stored the images like this.

```
items[
    {
        "image" : "images/item-1.png",
        "heading" : "heading-1",
        "text" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
    },
    {
        "image" : "images/item-2.png",
        "heading" : "heading-2",
        "text" : "Morbi tincidunt commodo scelerisque."
    },
    {
        "image" : "images/item-3.png",
        "heading" : "heading-3",
        "text" : "Duis porttitor diam vitae leo elementum accumsan."
    }
]
```

How do I do this with jquery / ajax?
I am beginner, can someone help? thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all it depends on what slider you use.
An abstract approach would be something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    getSlides();

})


function getSlides(){

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'script.php',
        data: {
            action: "get_slilder_images"
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
    request.done(function( response ) {
        createSlides(response);
        // fires on successfull reply
    });
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        // fires on error
    });
    request.done(function() {
        // fires everytime transaction completes with or withoute error
    }) 
}

function createSlides(slides){

    var container = $('#sliderContainer');
    var html = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){

        html += '<li class="slide"><span class="slide-header">' + slides[i].heading + '</span><img src="' + slides[i].image + '"><span class="slide-text">' + slides[i].text + '</span></li>';

    }

    html = '<ul class="slide-list">' + html + '</ul>';
    container.html(html);

    container.someSliderPlugin(); // here it depends on what slider you use, most of them take a list as input.

}
```